# How do you add authentication credentials to a web test on the AZURE portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a web app written in Node and hosted as an Azure web app. I have setup Application Insights web tests for other sites that do NOT require auth and these work fine. Now I need to test a route that requires authentication, but it is not obvious how to do this on the Azure Portal. Can this actually be done? I have seen some posts about doing this through Visual Studio but I really want to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the article here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview - if you don't want to touch code (and hence, redeploy) you cannot do what you are asking in the question.

Looks like diving deep into code is the only way